# Arcpy RasterToNumPyArray does not read floating point raster

Tags: arcpy, raster, gdal, numpy, memoryerror

I have below rasters:

1. One with dimension (13646, 7510) where INTEGER pixel values ranges from 0-14.
2. One with dimension (13646, 7510) where DOUBLE (upto 10 decimal places) pixel values ranges from 0-181257.

I can easily read 1 with RasterToNumPyArray but when I try to read second raster exception raised as below:

> return _RasterToNumPyArray(*args, **kwargs)
>
> MemoryError:

I tried with `scipy.misc` it also gives me error for 2 but reads well 1. I have some problem with GDAL since, I think, I have installed OSGEO64 while I am using Python 2.7 32 bit. So I want to avoid GDAL.

Now what is the way to read 2 in arcpy.
I am using rasterio in virtual environment now and I want to get rid of the mess of using virtual environment.

My machine details:

[image: details]

Comment: To do so you need over 1 GB of memory , obviously you don't have it or cannot access

Comment: Ahh! but I think I have that resources in my machine?

Comment: Raster pixel size is generally described in bits; "INTEGER" could refer to anything from 1-, 4-, 8-  13-, 16-, 32-, to 64-bit, which makes it difficult to gauge how much RAM the working raster requires. You state you're using a 32-bit Python, which is your issue -- It generally only has 1.2Gb of heap available to reference all objects.

Comment: @Vince I think you should copy/paste that comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raster pixel size is generally described in bits; "INTEGER" could refer to anything from 1-, 4-, 8- 13-, 16-, 32-, to 64-bit, which makes it difficult to gauge how much RAM the working raster requires. You state you're using a 32-bit Python, which is your issue -- It generally only has 1.2Gb of heap available to reference ***all*** objects (including the Python language itself).

An image with dimensions 13646 x 7510 has 102,481,460 pixels.  With 64-bit depth (IEEE "double" size), the contiguous memory required is 819,851,680 bytes (~782 Mb).  While this is a trivial amount of addressable space in a 64-bit application, it represents 2/3 of the heap in a 32-bit application, so even if you were able to allocate it, it's unlikely you'd be able to manipulate it without generating a memory error.

As a rule, memory errors are encountered due to 32-bit application use (the problem confounds solution in the addressable space).  The solution is to use a 64-bit application framework.  If you run out of memory with a 64-bit application, then it's a coding issue (*somebody* hasn't thought through the task well enough).